# How to reboot ubuntu of of live cd (USB) with ubuntu installed?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, uefi

After finding out how to fix my hard drive partitioning problem, I went to boot from a live usb only to find out that the try Ubuntu option didn't come up in the grub menu and would only take me either to the already installed Ubuntu 14.04 lts or windows 8.1. My computer has factory UEFI/EFI built in so I'm wondering whether this is due to me having Ubuntu installed already or whether it's an issue with UEFI. I can't run from CD since my laptop has no optical disk drive so my only option is to use usb. Is it simply a matter of adding a missing code to the files on the Live disk or do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange.Maybe it isn't booting from your USB at all and moving on to your already installed GRUB menu.

If that's what is happening and since you mentioned you have UEFI you should remake Ubuntu USB disk with Rufus and select UEFI boot in the Rufus's options.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.I'll check the files to make sure everything is ok, but apart from that I don't think I've done anything wrong.

Comment: By the way, since I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 Lts, can the iso file on the usb be the same or does it have to be a different Ubuntu update such as an upgrade to 14.10 or a downgrade? The last thing I want is to wait for Rufus to install the iso because for some reason on my system, instead of the two minute process advertised, I have to wait for over four hours until it's completed.

Comment: It doesn't matter what version of Ubuntu you have (installed ) ifor the disk to launch Try Ubuntu mode.
I am quite sure you aren't able to boot from you USB disk. That's probably because of UEFI / MBR partitioning issue.
Try making booting usb disk again with UEFI option selected in Rufus.